# Application of Slutsky's Theorem to binomial distributed RVs

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

I am currently doing some exercises for an exam in probability theory and am stuck with the following exercise:

Let $(X_n)$ be random variables which are binomialdistributed with parameter $n,p$ for $p\in (0,1)$. Show that
\begin{align}
\frac{X_n(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-np}{\sqrt{n}}\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(p,p(1-p))
\end{align}
where $\Rightarrow$ denotes convergence in distribution.
My try was to insert $S_n-S_n$ and split the sum which with the central limit theorem implies that one summand converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p))$. **EDIT**: This is false.

It remains to show that $\frac{X_n(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $p$ in probability and this is were I am stuck.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\frac{X_n(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-np}{\sqrt{n}} = \sigma\frac{X_n - np}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} + \frac{X_n}{n}$$ for $\sigma = \sqrt{p(1-p)}$

Additionally we have $$X_n \sim \sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$$ for $Y_k \sim Ber(p)$
So we get $$\frac{X_n - np}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sim \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k - np}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$ by the CLT and it's known that $$\frac{X_n}{n} \to p$$

So we get in total:
$$\frac{X_n(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})-np}{\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1) + p = \mathcal{N}(p,\sigma^2)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot :)